# In Java, is there a built-in or common kind of Stream that allows outputting, say, 5-bit data?

Tags: java, encoding, arrays, outputstream, bitarray

Right now I have a little routine that tries to efficiently segment a message into parts and the calculation requires appending characters individually to an `OutputStream`, typically `BAOS`, and then doing something like `byte[] packed = packData(baos)` and calculating the size from the packed size. This packing step is necessary because I am wasting bits when I do `baos.write(my5bitbyte)`.

So in the packing step I typically do something like this:

1. Take a bit set from the bytes of the `baos.toByteArray()`
2. Make a new bit set for constructing bytes
3. From each byte, take bits 0-4 and append them in the obvious way to the new bit set
4. Make a `byte[]` from the new bit set , padding the last up to 7 bits of the last byte

My question is this:

Is there any way or such a thing as a `BitOutputStream`? Or something similar? The way I currently do this seems rather stupid and I could definitely be smarter about it but I wonder whether I am overlooking something that already exists.

**Edit** After examining the source of `ByteArrayOutputStream` it seems obvious that it could be implemented in the exact same way for some `BitArrayOutputStream` because all it is is just a `byte[]` encapsulated with some fancy stuff, so you could do `boolean[]`. But I don't think it exists, now that I look into it further, and so my question becomes then...

So would this be a reasonable way to implement a `BitArrayOutputStream`?

```
class FixedLengthBitArrayOutputStream extends OutputStream {

    private boolean[][] buffer;
    private final int originalLength;
    private final int bitLength;
    private int position = 0;
    private int expansions = 0;

    FixedLengthBitArrayOutputStream(short bitLength, short length) {
        this.buffer = new boolean[length][bitLength];
        this.originalLength = length;
        this.bitLength = bitLength;
    }

    private int limitBeforeExpansion(double factor) {
        return Math.max(
                (int) Math.floor(factor * buffer.length),
                (int) Math.floor( (1 - Math.pow(factor, expansions + 1)) * buffer.length)
        );
    }

    private boolean needsExpansion() {
        return position > limitBeforeExpansion(0.8);
    }

    private void expandIfNecessary() {
        if (needsExpansion()) {
            expansions++;
            this.buffer = Arrays.copyOf(this.buffer, (int) Math.pow((double)this.originalLength, expansions + 1));
        }
    }

    public boolean[] bitValue(int number) throws IllegalStateException {

        int remainder = number;
        boolean[] bits = new boolean[this.bitLength];

        for (int i = this.bitLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int power = (int) Math.pow(2, i + 1);
            boolean value = remainder > power;
            bits[i] = value;
            if (value) {
                remainder -= power;
            }
        }

        if (remainder != 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException("whoa");

        return bits;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) throws IOException, IllegalStateException {
        expandIfNecessary();

        this.buffer[position] = bitValue(b);
        position++;
    }

    public byte[] toByteArray() {

        BitSet bitSet = new BitSet(this.position * this.bitLength);

        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            boolean[] bits = this.buffer[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < bits.length; j++) {
               bitSet.set( i * bits.length + j , bits[j] ); 
            }
        }

        return bitSet.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, because the smallest unit various protocols, devices, processors, ram,  etc use is byte.  You can just pad the byte with zeroes if you don;t need all the bits

Comment: The real question here is why you are using 5-bit encoding. Baudot went out with Telex machines 30 years ago.

Comment: Why not use a custom FilterOutputStream wrapping your ByteArrayOutputStream, and which would buffer the bytes it receives until they can be combined together, and written to the BAOS. The close() method would pad the last remaining bits, if any, write it to the BAOS, and close the BAOS.

Comment: @JBNizet nice way to go about it design wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A natural approach would be to write a separate output stream class that chains (or wraps) another output stream (the same way you chain writers, buffered streams and unbuffered streams).

The code could looks similar to this. I buffers several bits until it reaches a full byte and writes it to the output stream. I haven't test it though. Thus it'll likely contain a bug or two.

```
class PackedBitsOutputStream {

    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private int numBufferedBits;
    private byte bufferedBits;

    PackedBitsOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
        outputStream = os;
    }

    void writeBitSet(int data, int relevantBits) {
        bufferedBits = (byte) (bufferedBits | (data << bufferedBits));
        numBufferedBits += relevantBits;
        if (numBufferedBits >= 8) {
            outputStream.write(bufferedBits);
            numBufferedBits -= 8;
            bufferedBits = (byte) (data >> (relevantBits - numBufferedBits));
        }
    }

    void flush() {
        outputStream.write(bufferedBits);
        bufferedBits = 0;
        numBufferedBits = 0;
        outputStream.flush();
    }

    void close() {
        flush();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Note: *writeBitSet* currently can write 8 bits at once at most.